# Php path variables like java

Tags: java, php, web

I am trying to add variable to my url such as `www.mydomain.com/category/PRODUCT_NAME`

In java, I can do this with basically using @PathVariable in spring or request.param(PRODUCT_NAME) in sparkjava. Is there a easy way to do this?

I tried to search this but I do not know the terminology of Php. Could you help me with this please ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. It _might be_ that you refer to interpreting parts of a clean URL's path as request arguments. In that case take a look at request rewriting on the level of the http server and php's superglobal `$_GET` variable.

Comment: I want the last part of url would be dynamic actually. After I get the Product name from query, i started to create my webpage using database transactions

Comment: If you ant to get the request URI then you should use ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) and for the query string you should use ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])

Comment: But in this case, there would be no url mapping for this URL, am I right ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the environment variables,  so that you can use

```
<?php
echo 'My url is ' .$_ENV['URL'];
?>
```

in order to create an environment variable, you can use `putenv()` function

```
<?php
putenv("UNIQID=$uniqid");
?>
```

to get an environment variable

```
<?php
// Example use of getenv()
$ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
```

you can use an excellent package https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv to manage environment variables like below

`env(VARIABLE_NAME, defaultvalue)`